# Emacs org mode export paragraph in block to HTML, The content does not wrap

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

[image]

it became to one long straight bar, instead of showing as a block of the paragraph. I use `#+begin_example`. if I use quote it looks ok but I want to have the block looks.

Answer (score 2):

`#+begin_example` turns into `<pre class="example">`, and `<pre>` elements normally don't wrap. However, you can make them wrap with CSS. Add this somewhere to your document (I usually put this at the beginning):

```
#+begin_export html
  <style>
    pre.example { white-space: pre-wrap; }
  </style>
#+end_export
```

You might also try `white-space: normal` or `white-space: pre-line`. The default for `<pre>` elements is `white-space: pre`. There's a table of options and examples of how they look on [MDN's reference page for white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

You can also apply this to `src` blocks by adding a rule `pre.src { white-space: pre-wrap; }`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use Special Block Syntax

The special block is a type of [Greater Block](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html#Greater_Blocks).

For example, when the special block below is exported to HTML the `div` tag will be assigned `class="NAME"` attribute.

```
#+BEGIN_NAME
Contents of special block.
#+END_NAME
```

Below are the results after the special block is exported to `HTML`.

```
<div class="NAME">
<p>
Contents of special block.
</p>

</div>
```

Hope that helped!

---

> The code in this answer was tested using:
>   emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2.1
>   org-mode version:  9.1.2

Answer (score 0):

`#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE` is intended to be unbroken, as far as I know.  From the info page:

> You can include literal examples that should not be subjected to
>   markup.  Such examples will be typeset in monospace, so this is well
>   suited for source code and similar examples.

Probably the best way to handle this is to use a `#+BEGIN_HTML` block and style it manually.  You could also insert line breaks manually in the `EXAMPLE` block, but I doubt you want to do that.

Comment: Yeah...Manually use HTML is painful, so the best way is to use QUOTE? How about when I write some code inside of  ` #+begin_src `, sometimes I have one long line of code or multiline of comment, how to solve this?

Comment: As far as I know, in SRC blocks you'll have to do line breaks manually.  `fill-paragraph` (`M-q`) can do that for you.  Alternatively, maybe you could hook into the exporter to automatically run `fill-paragraph` on code blocks when exported, but that is a labyrinth I cannot help you with.  :)