# How to define custom paragraph types in org mode with custom fontification?

Tags: org-mode, font-lock

How can I define custom paragraph blocks in org mode with a custom fontification, for example something like

```
#+BEGIN_MYPAR
Some text 
#+END_MYPAR
```

Then I want for example that this block is displayed in orange font color, one point larger than the rest of the text, bold face and indented by one tab.

How can I do this?

**Edit**:

The question is about how things are displayed in the emacs buffer, not in exports (though this may have been a follow up question).

Comment: Use the `defblock` macro from https://alhassy.github.io/org-special-block-extras/ ;-)
---There's a `#+begin_orange` block ready for use, which can be adapted for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reach your goal quite simple if you use source blocks instead of special blocks.
Define your own major mode, say `mypar-mode` with the help of `define-generic-mode` or `define-derived-mode` and setup the fontification for that major mode like you want it.

Make sure that `org-src-fontify-natively` and `org-src-preserve-indentation` are both set to t such that the `mypar` source blocks in the Org buffer look as much as possible like the fontified source buffers.

If you have [`htmlize`](https://stable.melpa.org/#/htmlize) installed you get most of the wanted formatting in the HTML export for free.

A code example that I have tested with Emacs 27.1 and Org 9.3.7:

```el
(require 'org)
(require 'cl-lib)
(define-generic-mode mypar-mode
  nil ;; comment-list
  nil ;; keyword-list
  ;; font-lock-list:
  '(("^.*$"
     ;; match-highlight:
     (0 ;; subexpression
      ;; facename:
      `(face (:inherit default :foreground "orange" :height 1.5 :weight bold) ;; we use an anonymous face
         ;; indent:
         line-prefix "\t"
         wrap-prefix "\t")
      )))
  nil ;; auto-mode-list
  '((lambda ()
      "Make `line-prefix' and `wrap-prefix' work in the source fontification buffer."
      (setq-local font-lock-extra-managed-props '(line-prefix wrap-prefix))
      ));; function-list
  "Formatting MYPAR blocks.")

(defun org+-hack-org-fontification ()
  "Make `wrap-prefix' and `line-prefix' text properties work in Org buffers."
  (setq-local font-lock-extra-managed-props (cl-union
                         '(line-prefix wrap-prefix)
                         font-lock-extra-managed-props)))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org+-hack-org-fontification)
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t
      org-src-preserve-indentation t)
```

At last an image how a `mypar` source block looks like in Org:

[image: display of a mypar source block]

Comment: Is there an option such that latex fragment previews work also in your mypar environment?

Answer (score 1):

First note, that your question is a bit vague. Where do you want to have this special formatting of the paragraph -- in HTML-export or LaTeX-export? Or even in the representation of the Org-buffer in Emacs?

I give you here an answer for HTML- and LaTeX-export.

The main idea for HTML-export is that `MYPAR` determines the style class of the text in the [special block](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/42488/2370).

You can define your own style within `#+HTML_HEAD` meta-lines.

The main idea for LaTeX-export is that `MYPAR` determines the LaTeX environment where the text of the [special block](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-blocks-in-LaTeX-export.html) is put in. You can define that custom environment within `#+LATEX_HEADER` meta-lines.

An example:

```
Some text before my paragraph. Let this paragraph have some more text. It should have at least two lines.
#+BEGIN_MYPAR
Some text in my paragraph. Let this paragraph have some more text. It should have at least two lines. Even a third line would be nice to have. So we continue this text for some time.
#+END_MYPAR
Some text after my paragraph. Let this paragraph have some more text. It should have at least two lines.

* Style :noexport:
This section is just for definition of HTML and LaTeX formatting.
#+HTML_HEAD: <style>.MYPAR { color:orange; text-indent:8em; font-weight:bold; foint-size:110% }</style>
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xcolor}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newdimen\myparindent\myparindent8em
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newdimen\myparwidth\myparwidth\textwidth\advance\myparwidth-\myparindent
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{MYPAR}{\par\noindent\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{\myparwidth}\bf\color{orange}\fontsize{1em}{1.2em}\selectfont}{\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}\end{minipage}\par\prevdepth\tpd}
See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/indenting-a-whole-paragraph for using ~minipage~ for indenting a whole paragraph.
```

Comment: Thanks, but see my edit above. The question is indeed about how it is displayed in the emacs buffer.